# Why call object class parameter method linseed of fixed data type parameter in inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, overload-resolution

Case 1:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Print(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass Print(int)");
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void Print(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass Print(int)");
    }

    public void Print(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass Print(object)");
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DerivedClass objDerivedClass = new DerivedClass();
    int i = 10;
    objDerivedClass.Print(i);
}
```

Output is `DerivedClass Print(object)`.

Case 2:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void Print(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass Print(int)");
    }

    public void Print(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass Print(object)");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeClass objSomeClass = new SomeClass();
    int i = 10;
    objSomeClass.Print(i);
}
```

Output is `DerivedClass Print(int)`.

After calling `objDerivedClass.Print(i);` method, the output is `DerivedClass Print(object)`. I don't understand why the method `Print(object obj)` is being called instead of `Print(int i)`.

If `DerivedClass` does not inherit `BaseClass` class then output is `DerivedClass Print(int)`.

Please explain.......

Comment: Section 7.5.3 of the C# language spec is about overload resolution, so you should refer to that. Given the behaviour, I would assume that, if there are multiple possible candidates, a member of the current type is preferred to an overloaded member of the base type. It's not an issue really, because you can always write the overload to call the override if the argument is the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how overload resolution works with inheritance:

1. The function that includes the `override` modifier is excluded from the set of candidates.
2. Since the function with the `object` parameter can be used, then the function that is declared in the base is removed from the set of candidates.

The winner is the function with the `object` parameter.

According to [Eric Lippert (from Microsoft)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3648227/3215948):

> This is by design and for a good reason. This design helps prevent the Brittle Base Class problem. C# was designed to make it easier and safer to write "versioned" components, and this rule is a big part of that.

When no inheritance is used, both functions are candidates, and the one that is more specific is used. The winner is the function with the `int` parameter.